# I am getting this error :-Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory please tell me the solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**app.js it is main file**

```
// importing the module
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const app = express()
require("./db/conn")

// defining a localhost port number  
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// defining and using static files(i.e html)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")))

// defining handle bar engine
app.set("view engine", "hbs")

// this is just for test
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index")
})

// creating our localhost
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Connection Successfull");
})
```

**this is my index.hbs file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**error**

> ```
> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\src\views"
>   at Function.render (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
>   at ServerResponse.render (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
>   at D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\src\app.js:18:9
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at next (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>   at Route.dispatch (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>   at Function.process_params (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>   at SendStream.error (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
>   at SendStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
>   at SendStream.error (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\send\index.js:270:17)
>   at SendStream.onStatError (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\send\index.js:421:12)
>   at next (D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\send\index.js:763:28)
>   at D:\Programs\Projects\mern_project\node_modules\send\index.js:771:23
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set view property

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

before setting view engine

Example

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

// defining and using static files(i.e html)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")))

//engine added after editing answer
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));

// necessary for templates
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// defining handle bar engine
app.set("view engine", "hbs")

// this is just for test
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index")
})
```

Edited to add:
Hbs engine was not declared. Should be before set view

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const path = require('path')


app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'../views'));
```

Comment: Try adding a bit more context to the answer not just the code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
`const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();


console.log(__dirname);

const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, "../public");
// app.use(express.static(staticPath));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));

app.set("view engine", "hbs");


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.write("<h1>Hello from home page</h1>");
    res.write("<p>Hey</p>");
    res.send();
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("listening to the port");
})`
```

```html
Note-->1.This error is telling that it is not able to find views directory.As we know that while using template engines we need to use folder/directory as views.So for including it in your index.js page you have to use this code--> 

app.set ('views', path.join (__dirname, '../xyz'));

   Note-->3.If you want to customize/change the directory/folder name as(xyz) instead of views then we have to use-->
app.set ('views', path.join (__dirname, '../views'));

Note-->2.Here two default("/") page or root is given but express follows top to bottom rule,if it finds the first root then it do not see other one.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).