# Why this error is showing Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "E:\node js\Express js\templates"

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

The index file is there in view folder then also this error is showing
I searched so much about it but not getting the answer please help me with this

const express = require("express")
const app = express();

```
const path = require("path")
const hbs = require('hbs')

const port = 3000;

const template = path.join(\__dirname,"../templates")
const partialPath = path.join(\__dirname,"../templates/parial")

// to set the view engine

app.set('view engine','hbs')
app.set('views',template)
hbs.registerPartials(partialPath)

// template engine route

app.get('/',(req,res) =\> {
res.render('index',{
channelName : "Raza"
});
})

app.get('/about',(req,res) =\> {
res.render("about")
})

app.get("/",(req,res) =\> {
res.send("hello from the server");
});

app.listen(port,() =\> {
console.log(`listening to port no ${port} `);
});`
```

Error :

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "E:\node js\Express js\templates"
    at Function.render (E:\node js\Express js\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:597:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\node js\Express js\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at E:\node js\Express js\src\index.js:107:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node js\Express                js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\node js\Express js\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\node js\Express js\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node js\Express         js\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\node js\Express js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (E:\node js\Express js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (E:\node js\Express js\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)


 [My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcZGW.png)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express: Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67331959/express-error-failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-directory) [I am getting this error :-Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory please tell me the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877741/i-am-getting-this-error-error-failed-to-lookup-view-index-in-views-director)

Comment: According to your folder structure, the path to your views should be `../templates/views`, not `../templates`. Also, there is a typo in `../templates/parial` - it should be `../templates/partial`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I tried so many things but It was a silly mistake that you helped me to solve,thank you so so much